# Opening and Using NotePad like program from the Ubuntu command line in WSL (Windows)

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, text, editor, notepadqq

I really want to start using Linux, especially Ubuntu distro systems because I hear such great things about them and the fact that it very community based, which I really love.

Anyway, is there a command I can type into Ubuntu for WSL command prompt that would allow me to open a .conf type file to make changes?

Comment: Run `nano file.conf`

Comment: How did you install Notepadqq, and what type of package is it?